# If $f(x, y) = 0$ on an open subset of $\Bbb R^2$, then $f = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $f \in R[x, y]$ be such that there exists a non-empty open set $U \subseteq \Bbb R^2$
such that
$f(x, y) = 0$ for every $(x, y) \in U$. Show that $f = 0$.

If $f$ were continuous and on the real line, I could prove it, but right now I'm stumped. Please help.

Comment: Fix $(u_1,u_2)\in U$, then $x\mapsto f(x,u_2)$ is a polynomial in $x$. How many roots does it have?

Comment: @Surb Infinite roots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $f$ is a polynomial in two variables but when we fix some point $(x_0,y_0) \in U$ then we know $f(x_0,y_0) = 0$. Furthermore, as $U$ is open we know there is some neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0)$ in $U$ and so $f(x,y_0)$ (viewed as a single-variable polynomial) has infinitely many roots. A polynomial cannot have more roots than its degree if it is of degree $\geq 1$ and so $f(x,y_0) = 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Similarly, we can show $f(x_0,y) = 0$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Now notice we can always choose $(x_0,y_0) \neq (0,0)$ so either $x_0$ or $y_0$ is not zero. Now $f$'s general form can be stated as $$ \sum_{0\leq \: i_1+i_2 \: \leq n, \: i_1\in \mathbb{N}, \: i_2\in\mathbb{N}} a_{i_1,i_2}x^{i_1}y^{i_2}$$ for some $n$ (which is the degree, if the polynomial is not 0). If $x_0$ is nonzero, how can the above be the zero polynomial if we fix $x$ to be $x_0$? Only if $a_{i_1,i_2}$ are zero for each $i_1,i_2$ or in other words, only if $f(x,y) = 0$.

Comment: Sir, from where can I solve more problems like this? I need a good book to study this topic. Please guide I'm preparing for an exam.

Comment: @ShreyaSingh what is the topic? Polynomials?

Comment: (1) Sir the topic based on this question. I think its topology. Please suggest where I can study more problems like this. (2) Topics in my exam are Abstract algebra, Linear algebra, Real analysis, Topology and Complex Analysis. I'm studying from Linear algebra done right, Rudin, Masayoshi, Teodora, Dummit and Foote. But I have no good book for such questions in Complex Analysis & Topology.

Comment: I must say I'm surprised - the question you asked compared to the great difficulty and breadth of your exams is completely different. All of those topics in a single exam? To be honest, your books on Real Analysis should be filled with questions similar to this and far more difficult but ANY of these books should have difficult problems. This question above would not really be considered a "topic", it just uses the idea that polynomials have a finite number of roots if they are nonzero. I would suggest looking at your books and doing exercises given in your course.

Comment: Sir may I please ask you for help if I get stuck somewhere. I completed my BS in December & my entrance exams for masters are in 2 months and I have no guidance. I won't disturb you. I just need a little help sometimes.

Comment: @ShreyaSingh You can do this but may I suggest: asking a friend taking your courses, asking a supervisor/lecturer, asking Mathematics Stack Exchange again with more questions and most of all *really trying the questions*. I know that last part sounds condescending and I of all people know how tempting it is to look up solutions but many questions can take *hours* to solve but the best way to get better is to spend those hours thinking, even if it feels like you're getting nowhere. Finally, you should keep in mind that I haven't even finished my 1st year of my degree, so I'm not an expert!

Comment: Okay Sir, thank you very much